# Deploy API REST IBM Hyperledger Composer Blockchain (bad flag in substitute command: 'U' ERROR)

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm getting this error trying to deploy a card to a working blockchain on cloud, any idea? Thanks in advance. I'm using a mac, following the guide (Kubernetes installed/configured well, I think):

https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/interacting/

```
./create/create_composer-rest-server.sh --paid --business-network-card /Users/sm/jsblock/tutorial-network/PeerAdmin@fabric-network.card
Configured to setup a paid storage on ibm-cs
Preparing yaml file for create composer-rest-server
sed: 1: "s/%COMPOSER_CARD%//User ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'U'
Creating composer-rest-server pod
Running: kubectl create -f /Users/sm/jsblock/ibm-container-service/cs-offerings/scripts/../kube-configs/composer-rest-server.yaml
error: no objects passed to create
Composer rest server created successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in that document.  And you are also specifying the Peer Admin card when you need to use a Network Admin Card.

There are 2 sets of 'parallel' documents for **paid** and **free** clusters.  The command you are using has `--paid` in it in error.  If you remove --paid and use the Network Admin Card I think it will solve the problem.

Your command will look something like this: `./create/create_composer-rest-server.sh --business-network-card admin@YOUR-network`

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, but it didn't work for me.
I tried again with the install proccess (deployed blockchain instance seemed to work weall): https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/simple/

But I noticed that the script:
./create_all.sh
 

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-issues/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

I tried again with the install proccess (deployed blockchain instance seemed to work weall): https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/simple/

But I noticed that the script:

```
./create_all.sh
```

...never ended (mostly an internal kubernetes problems I guess). And I reset the installation:

```
./delete_all.sh
./create_all.sh
```

I tried again, now everything Ok. I could get my awesome API REST talking with my Hyperledger Blockchain, deployed on IBM Cloud. Ready to develop something amazing.